# Python: Problem with parsing e.g. Greek characters with parse_mathematica

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

SymPy provides a package, `sympy.parsing.mathematica`, for parsing Mathematica code. The old parsing function, `mathematica`, seems to be able to handle e.g. Greek characters fine:

```
from sympy.parsing.mathematica import mathematica
mathematica('λ')
Out[]: 
λ
```

As of SymPy v. 1.11, the `mathematica` function is deprecated, and is replaced by `parse_mathematica`. This function, however, seems unable to handle the simple example above:

```
from sympy.parsing.mathematica import parse_mathematica
parse_mathematica('λ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...

File "<string>", line unknown
SyntaxError: unable to create a single AST for the expression
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work and what the error message "SyntaxError: unable to create a single AST for the expression" means? Googling on this error message (in quotes) appears to give no hits.

Comment: Looks like a bug so best to open a GitHub issue: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Ok, will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [**`symbols()`**](https://www.sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial/notebooks/01-intro-sympy.html) instead, perhaps ?

```
from sympy import *
symbols('lambda')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it wouldn't really be an option to do so in my application. Also, I think that the newer version of the mathematica parser ought to be able to handle the stuff that the old (deprecated one) could handle.